# When I convert the obtained road network data into a geodataframes structure, why does the list element appear in the highway column?

Tags: python, list, geospatial, osmnx

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('成都市',network_type='all')
G = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G)
# 将图形转换为节点和边的GeoDataFrames类型
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
gdf_edges
```

So I got the following image
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d5J1.png
the result was `[motorway_link, trunk]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, OSMnx simplifies the graph unless you use `simplify=False`. See [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph) for details:

> Some of the resulting consolidated edges may comprise multiple OSM ways, and if so, their multiple attribute values are stored as a list.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help, I changed the code, as
G = ox.graph_from_place('成都市',network_type='all',simplify=False), and I solved the problem.